# What is the regex to match against the output from Date.now?

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to match on a value that is outputted from Date.now() in JavaScript. I have googled around, but cant seem to find anything related. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a sample:

```
?date=1390760831642
```

Comment: `Date.now()` returns a number, i.e. a sequence of digits when treated as a string. Are you looking for `\d+` then? If you want to get the parameters in a URL, that's a different question.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to match the millisecond epoch timestamp against a regular expression. What is it that you hope to achieve?

Comment: Could I use something as basic as this? \d{13}

Comment: @jrutter: Yes, but `\d{13}` only validates it's 13 digits, not that it's actually a meaningful timestamp.

Comment: Do you how to calculate the actual timestamp? Im guessing it would be a bit more trickY!

Comment: Isin't there a function to format the output? Otherwise calculations, seconds since 1900, etc..

Comment: Oh, and I will add that `\d{13}` is only relevant for the time when there are 13 digits representing milliseconds since Epoch.  If the date were say January 1, 1980 or January 1, 2142, you would not have 13 digits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
\?[d]\W+\d{13}/
```

Comment: Probably should be like `/^\?[d]\w*\W+\d{13}$/`